# Apache poi и поля в документе Word

Tags: java, apache-poi

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть шаблон документа Word, в котором имеется некоторый набор полей, в которые необходимо выгрузить соответствующие данные: ФИО, дата и так далее.

Можно ли в Apache POI как-то получить эти поля и записать в них значения?

Comment: если коротко, то можно

Comment: Можно, он для этого и предназначен.

Comment: А если поподробней, то есть ли пример кода.

Comment: Если просто пишешь парсер где обрабатываешь каждую строку и сверяешь.

Comment: @RenatAhmetshin лучше вот это читай https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi_word/apache_poi_word_quick_guide.htm

Answer (score 0):

1. Здесь [Java Word (.docx) documents with docx4j](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/java-word-docx-documents-with-docx4j.html) есть пример решения похожей задачи, но с использованием docx4j.
2. Ещё посмотрите [XDocReport](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/wiki) - ещё один способ решить вашу проблему.